# Rbind a dataframe from a list of dataframes to a dataframe in a different list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary, lapply, rbind

I have two lists of dataframes, each dataframe in the two lists have the same name and of the same number of columns.  I want to rbind the matching dataframe names from list 2 onto list 1.

snippets of my two lists below

```
l1 <-list(Fe = structure(c("Min", "Max", "Median", "Mean", "Std Dev", 
"Coeff. Variation", "Dev. From Cert Mean", "   NA", "   NA", 
"   NA", "  NaN", "   NA", "  NA", "  NaN", "56.18", "56.83", 
"56.50", "56.48", "0.218", "0.39", " 0.13", "56.31", "56.53", 
"56.41", "56.41", "0.080", "0.14", " 0.01", "56.29", "56.39", 
"56.32", "56.33", "0.034", "0.06", "-0.15", "56.40", "56.73", 
"56.51", "56.53", "0.125", "0.22", " 0.22", "56.26", "56.53", 
"56.32", "56.36", "0.116", "0.20", "-0.09", "56.20", "56.70", 
"56.50", "56.45", "0.176", "0.31", " 0.08", "56.10", "56.46", 
"56.36", "56.29", "0.150", "0.27", "-0.21", "56.10", "56.83", 
"56.41", "56.41", "0.153", "0.27", ""), .Dim = c(7L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("LabMinSummary", "LabMaxSummary", "LabMedianSummary", "LabMeanSummary", 
    "lab.SDSummary", "cv.summmary", "LabDevMean.Summary"), c("", 
    "2", "3", "4", "5", "7", "8", "10", "12", ""))), SiO2 = structure(c("Min", 
"Max", "Median", "Mean", "Std Dev", "Coeff. Variation", "Dev. From Cert Mean", 
"7.63", "7.73", "7.67", "7.67", "0.033", "0.44", "-1.09", "7.59", 
"7.84", "7.72", "7.71", "0.091", "1.18", "-0.55", "7.62", "7.81", 
"7.70", "7.72", "0.079", "1.02", "-0.48", "7.84", "7.96", "7.89", 
"7.89", "0.048", "0.61", " 1.75", "7.65", "7.83", "7.76", "7.76", 
"0.060", "0.77", " 0.01", "7.68", "7.94", "7.83", "7.82", "0.086", 
"1.10", " 0.84", "7.62", "7.87", "7.79", "7.77", "0.111", "1.43", 
" 0.19", "7.64", "7.82", "7.70", "7.70", "0.065", "0.84", "-0.68", 
"7.59", "7.96", "7.74", "7.74", "0.097", "1.25", ""), .Dim = c(7L, 
10L), .Dimnames = list(c("LabMinSummary", "LabMaxSummary", "LabMedianSummary", 
"LabMeanSummary", "lab.SDSummary", "cv.summmary", "LabDevMean.Summary"
), c("", "2", "3", "4", "5", "7", "8", "10", "12", ""))), Al2O3 = structure(c("Min", 
"Max", "Median", "Mean", "Std Dev", "Coeff. Variation", "Dev. From Cert Mean", 
"2.00", "2.03", "2.01", "2.01", "0.010", "0.52", "-0.16", "2.00", 
"2.03", "2.01", "2.01", "0.010", "0.52", "-0.16", "1.99", "2.03", 
"2.01", "2.01", "0.013", "0.66", "-0.49", "2.02", "2.05", "2.02", 
"2.03", "0.012", "0.58", " 0.50", "  NA", "  NA", "  NA", " NaN", 
"   NA", "  NA", "  NaN", "2.01", "2.05", "2.04", "2.03", "0.017", 
"0.82", " 0.78", "1.98", "2.02", "2.01", "2.01", "0.015", "0.77", 
"-0.45", "  NA", "  NA", "  NA", " NaN", "   NA", "  NA", "  NaN", 
"1.98", "2.05", "2.01", "2.01", "0.016", "0.77", ""), .Dim = c(7L, 
10L), .Dimnames = list(c("LabMinSummary", "LabMaxSummary", "LabMedianSummary", 
"LabMeanSummary", "lab.SDSummary", "cv.summmary", "LabDevMean.Summary"
), c("", "2", "3", "4", "5", "7", "8", "10", "12", ""))))

l2 <- list(Fe = c("Count", "0", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"42"), SiO2 = c("Count", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"48"), Al2O3 = c("Count", "6", "6", "6", "6", "0", "6", "6", 
"0", "36"))
```

I tried

```
l3 <- Map(rbind(l1,l2))

l3 <- do.call(rbind,Map(l1,l2))
```

Not really sure where to go to from here

``

Comment: `l2` is a list of character vector and not list of dataframes. How would your final expected output look?

Comment: @Ronak Shah I realised the list where different lengths so I have fixed that up.  I want to add the Fe from the l2 onto the bottom of Fe in l1 ( i guess technically its a vector onto a dataframe) but rbind would work outside a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `rbind` like below

```
> Map(rbind, l1, l2)
$Fe
                                         2       3       4       5
LabMinSummary      "Min"                 "   NA" "56.18" "56.31" "56.29"
LabMaxSummary      "Max"                 "   NA" "56.83" "56.53" "56.39"
LabMedianSummary   "Median"              "   NA" "56.50" "56.41" "56.32"
LabMeanSummary     "Mean"                "  NaN" "56.48" "56.41" "56.33"
lab.SDSummary      "Std Dev"             "   NA" "0.218" "0.080" "0.034"
cv.summmary        "Coeff. Variation"    "  NA"  "0.39"  "0.14"  "0.06"
LabDevMean.Summary "Dev. From Cert Mean" "  NaN" " 0.13" " 0.01" "-0.15"
                   "Count"               "0"     "6"     "6"     "6"
                   7       8       10      12
LabMinSummary      "56.40" "56.26" "56.20" "56.10" "56.10"
LabMaxSummary      "56.73" "56.53" "56.70" "56.46" "56.83"
LabMedianSummary   "56.51" "56.32" "56.50" "56.36" "56.41"
LabMeanSummary     "56.53" "56.36" "56.45" "56.29" "56.41"
lab.SDSummary      "0.125" "0.116" "0.176" "0.150" "0.153"
cv.summmary        "0.22"  "0.20"  "0.31"  "0.27"  "0.27"
LabDevMean.Summary " 0.22" "-0.09" " 0.08" "-0.21" ""
                   "6"     "6"     "6"     "6"     "42"

$SiO2
                                         2       3       4       5
LabMinSummary      "Min"                 "7.63"  "7.59"  "7.62"  "7.84"
LabMaxSummary      "Max"                 "7.73"  "7.84"  "7.81"  "7.96"
LabMedianSummary   "Median"              "7.67"  "7.72"  "7.70"  "7.89"
LabMeanSummary     "Mean"                "7.67"  "7.71"  "7.72"  "7.89"
lab.SDSummary      "Std Dev"             "0.033" "0.091" "0.079" "0.048"
cv.summmary        "Coeff. Variation"    "0.44"  "1.18"  "1.02"  "0.61"
LabDevMean.Summary "Dev. From Cert Mean" "-1.09" "-0.55" "-0.48" " 1.75"
                   "Count"               "6"     "6"     "6"     "6"
                   7       8       10      12
LabMinSummary      "7.65"  "7.68"  "7.62"  "7.64"  "7.59"
LabMaxSummary      "7.83"  "7.94"  "7.87"  "7.82"  "7.96"
LabMedianSummary   "7.76"  "7.83"  "7.79"  "7.70"  "7.74"
LabMeanSummary     "7.76"  "7.82"  "7.77"  "7.70"  "7.74"
lab.SDSummary      "0.060" "0.086" "0.111" "0.065" "0.097"
cv.summmary        "0.77"  "1.10"  "1.43"  "0.84"  "1.25"
LabDevMean.Summary " 0.01" " 0.84" " 0.19" "-0.68" ""
                   "6"     "6"     "6"     "6"     "48"

$Al2O3
                                         2       3       4       5
LabMinSummary      "Min"                 "2.00"  "2.00"  "1.99"  "2.02" 
LabMaxSummary      "Max"                 "2.03"  "2.03"  "2.03"  "2.05"
LabMedianSummary   "Median"              "2.01"  "2.01"  "2.01"  "2.02"
LabMeanSummary     "Mean"                "2.01"  "2.01"  "2.01"  "2.03"
lab.SDSummary      "Std Dev"             "0.010" "0.010" "0.013" "0.012"
cv.summmary        "Coeff. Variation"    "0.52"  "0.52"  "0.66"  "0.58"
LabDevMean.Summary "Dev. From Cert Mean" "-0.16" "-0.16" "-0.49" " 0.50"
                   "Count"               "6"     "6"     "6"     "6"
                   7       8       10      12
LabMinSummary      "  NA"  "2.01"  "1.98"  "  NA"  "1.98"
LabMaxSummary      "  NA"  "2.05"  "2.02"  "  NA"  "2.05"
LabMedianSummary   "  NA"  "2.04"  "2.01"  "  NA"  "2.01"
LabMeanSummary     " NaN"  "2.03"  "2.01"  " NaN"  "2.01"
lab.SDSummary      "   NA" "0.017" "0.015" "   NA" "0.016"
cv.summmary        "  NA"  "0.82"  "0.77"  "  NA"  "0.77"
LabDevMean.Summary "  NaN" " 0.78" "-0.45" "  NaN" ""
                   "0"     "6"     "6"     "0"     "36"
```

Comment: not quite.  unfortunately there was an error in my l1 list, which I have fixed up.  I want to add the Fe in l1 onto the bottom of Fe in l1 and then for SiO2 and so forth

Comment: yep thats what I need. looks like I was close with my first attempt

Answer (score 1):

Or use `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2(l1, l2, rbind)
```

Comment: thanks this worked as well. always good to have multiple ways of getting to the end result